# Create automatic message on Slack from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, slack, simplepoll

I want to be able to publish a ["Simple Poll"](https://getvim.slack.com/apps/A0HFW7MR6-simple-poll) automaticlly from Jenkins once a job is done, into specific channels in Slack. This is what I have in my config.jenkinsfile:

```
            slackSend (
            channel: ‘#test1,#test2`,
            color: '#008000',
            message: "/simplepoll \”Hello World, are you OK?\” \”Test1\” \”Test2\” \”Test3\” \”Test4\” \”Test5\” \”Test6\” no-preview"
        )
```

But in Slack instead of creating the pull I see:

"/simplepoll \”Hello World, are you OK?\” \”Test1\” \”Test2\” \”Test3\” \”Test4\” \”Test5\” \”Test6\” no-preview"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to pass a """ multiline string """ without escaping double quotes?